# Einstein's equations in a world with energy sources/sinks

Tags: general-relativity, tensor-calculus, stress-energy-momentum-tensor

Einstein's equations are typically given by $G_{\mu\nu} = T_{\mu\nu}$. One of the justifications for using the Einstein tensor $G_{\mu\nu}$ is that it has the (geometric) property of being divergence-free, i.e. $\nabla_{\mu} G^{\mu\nu} = 0$, which is necessary because in typical situations the stress-energy-momentum is a conserved current, i.e. $\nabla_\mu T^{\mu\nu} = 0$.

Now suppose we wish to model a universe where energy is spontaneously created, so that $\nabla_\mu T^{\mu\nu} \neq 0$. $G_{\mu\nu}$ is no longer an appropriate RHS in this situation because the property $\nabla_\mu G^{\mu\nu} = 0$ is an immutable geometric property of the Einstein tensor. My question is: is there a "canonical" way to modify the Einstein equations in presence of energy sources?

Comment: One early model of gravity with sources (to constrain the universe to obey steady-state cosmology rather than the big bang) was the Hoyle theory, which added the $C$-field to the EFEs simply to perform this job, which was simply a vector field, andthey added the term $\nabla_\mu C_\nu$ to the equations.

Comment: The issue is the covariant conservative of energy-momentum is a consequence of the diffeomorphism invariance of the action. It takes some quite serious modifications to have $\nabla T \neq 0$.